# Custom package for jaxb DTOs from wsdl

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, wsdl

I have ONLY wsdl for a third party service. I need to generate the jaxb dtos to a custom package without editing the wsdl. I know we can do the same using a binding file. But when i referred many binding files, they uses schema file (xsd). But for me, i dont have any schema. I think, i need to extract schema from wsdl and then generate binding file.

Can anyone help me how to perform this? or if there is any other method to do it. can u please share?. Thanks in advance.

*PS - third party wsdl is having 1000+ lines.

Answer (score 0):

try using wsdl2java with ant.

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html
http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/ant/axis-wsdl2java.html#

Something related to wsdl2java i had asked earlier (incase u face a similar issue).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502425/binding-xml-for-wsdl2java-two-declarations-cause-a-collision-in-the-objectfacto